# Can I connect a switch to a router AND share internet over that same wire

Tags: networking, home-networking

I want to know if I can set up my home network like this so every device is on the same network. Basically, the wireless router becomes the router and the DSL Modem/Router does nothing but provide internet:

[image]

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Since your modem also has the router build into it, you would just want to disable the Wireless Router's DHCP server via the web interface. This would allow the wireless connections to pull a local ip address from the DSL Modem's router. THe Wired connections will get an local IP address from the DSL Modem's router.

You would not be able to use your Wireless Router to serve the IP Addresses from its DHCP server while being on the same network as the switch's connections.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know if I can set up my home network ... so every device is on the same network.

Yes, with proper connections and configuration of the DSL Modem/Router and Wireless Router.

> Basically, the wireless router becomes the router and the DSL Modem/Router does nothing but provide internet.
>   Is that possible?

That would be possible, but not the way you have it diagrammed.

The connections would be DSL Modem/Router to (WAN port of) Wireless Router to the switch.
You will have to reconfigure the DSL Modem/Router to a "bridge" mode to disable its router so that you could use the router in the Wireless Router.
You will then have to configure the Wireless Router to connect to your ISP.
You might have to "clone" the MAC address of the DSL Modem/Router to the Wireless Router (so that your ISP will accept the connection).

If you want to connect the devices exactly as you originally diagrammed it, then you have to use the router that is built-in to the DSL Modem/Router and use the Wireless Router as just as a wireless access point (WAP).
You will have to
(1) disable the DHCP server in the Wireless Router,
(2) assign a static IP address to the the Wireless Router's LAN interface that is not within the address pool handed out by the DSL Modem/Router's DHCP server, and
(3) connect one of the Wireless Router's LAN port (not the WAN port!) to the switch using a Cat5 (or better) cable.

Answer (score 0):

This would depend on the router but isnt a very ideal configuration. You should have your router sit between the LAN and the WAN, not as an end-node on the LAN.

Most home routers will have a few LAN ports and one WAN port, and you will probably run into problems using a single interface to have a public and private IP and routing between them. It is possible in theory, but highly impractical and unlikely.  If your modem supports routing, you should just disable any routing on the wireless router, and use it strictly as an access point.